# Error starting Foo: Class 'net.rim.device.api.system.WLANListener' not found

Tags: blackberry

I'm new to Blackberry development and have come across something I don't understand.
I have an application that I have been working on it supports Blackberry OS 5 to 7.1 and works on them all apart from OS 6. For some strange reason I get:

Error starting Foo: Class 'net.rim.device.api.system.WLANListener' not found

on Blackberry OS 6 only! There is no OS specific code (as far as I know). This is after I have cleaned both code and Simulator (using Eclipse) and signed the code. Most of the time the application refuses to install on the OS 6 device - of course, it works perfectly fine on other OS versions. What could be causing this?

Comment: Implement very simple application that uses 'net.rim.device.api.system.WLANListener' class and run it on the same device. Do you get the same error for this simple app?

Comment: I did implement something very simple and it appeared to work (or at least not error). Debug in simulator is showing - AM: Starting Foo
[0.0] VM:LINK Foo
[0.0] Class 'net.rim.device.api.system.WLANListener' not found.[0.0] 
[0.0] Linker error: 'VerifyError' for Foo
[0.0] VM:CLRCv=0
[0.0] AM: Error starting Foo: Class <br/>'net.rim.device.api.system.WLANListener' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I’ve finally discovered the problem after a lot of research and trial and error.

If the application is over 64kb in size rapc the Blackberry compiler splits the file into multiple files called sibling COD’s. The COD file that you see in the deliverables folder is actually a zip file containing the main COD file and all its siblings. They should all be 64kb or smaller although I have still seen the when first COD file is larger.

The fix is to make sure that you have no files in your project larger than 64kb. I had images that were larger although I have read that someone had a class that when compiled came to greater than 64kb causing issues, so they split the class up and solved the problem that they were having.

The symptoms were strange, I was getting an inconsistent compilation for different OS versions resulting in different strange issues for different devices, I was thinking at the time that it seemed like a linking issue, it seems like I wasn’t too far off. Thank you.